# Secure link hash for password reset system

Tags: php, laravel

Just want to be sure if that's the "right way" and most importantly if it's "secure way". I'm making simple form for someone who want's to reset password (not logged in). I don't want to use Laravel way (no dedicated database for that). Simply I'm sending crypted link, link is valid for 10 minutes.

```
public function sendConfirmationLink(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->firstOrFail();

    $parameters = [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'date' => Carbon::now(),
        'type' => 'password_reset',
    ];

    $passwordResetLink = Crypt::encrypt($parameters);

    SendPasswordResetLink::dispatch($user, $passwordResetLink)->onQueue('high');
}
```

Later on, I'm decrypting that hash and I'm making password change.

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'hash' => 'required',
        'new_password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    try {
        $decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($request->get('hash'));

        $password = Hash::make($request->get('new_password'));

        $user = User::where('id', $decrypted['user_id'])->firstOrFail();

        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();
    } catch (DecryptException $e) {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

If I'm right... that "link" will be extremely difficult to crack and it's valid for only 10 minutes. Is it in any way less secure then native Laravel version with similar code stored in database?

Yes I know that Laravel Auth can do it for me. I want use my method in more then password reset so I'm looking for answear if it's secure this way.

Comment: Is it secure? It could be if the encryption algorithm is secure and the key is never compromised. Though you really shouldn't need to encrypt anything to accomplish this. You only need a unique value that's unpredictable. So something like a UUID or even a very large random number from a good source of entropy is good enough. I have no idea why you want to avoid storing information in the database, but even with encryption you would at least need to store the key in the database (*or somewhere*). So again, not sure why you want to avoid this.

Comment: @Sherif if I'm right Laravel's Crypt:: use my app key stored in env. So it's well secured. I try to make it super simple. With that code I don't need to store record in database. Link is delivered to the user via e-mail and user can change password.

Comment: Avoiding storing the information in the database doesn't actually make it any simpler, just FYI. And no, the fact that it uses your app key doesn't necessarily say anything about how secure it is.

Comment: @Sammitch with random 32-char I can't limit that code to specyfic time period. Hipotetic form with new password and input for that random code will be exposed to public so without throttle it can be insecure. Also without database I can't store that random code anywhere so how can I check if that's the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Crypt library from Laravel uses a combination of `OpenSSL` and `AES-256-CBC` with a `MAC signing`. I think for a 10 min period, that should be safe enough.

A more serious problem is, that you can't "disable" a link after usage. So theoretically everyone with the link can change the account password infinite times (in a 10 min period).

A solution for that problem could be, that you add the current password hash into your link-hash and then compare that. In that case the password change would only work one-time per link.

Comment: Oh! That's a very good idea with current password inside that hash. Eliminates problem with more then one change per generated link.

Comment: yeah if you implement that too, your system should be pretty safe imo. Please mark my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.